# Action bar custom view

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I want to declare a custom view, BUT I also want the home logo with up icon to appear on the left with its default functionality. How can I achieve to use both?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Best way is to use XML styles:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom</item>
</style>
```

Then simply set this theme as either the application theme or activity them in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You can also do the same in code without any theme changes:
`getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM|ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);`