# How to set drawables on actionbar of my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-drawable

I'm developing an application in which I have to put drawables on top of the actionbar and have to update then from time to time. Here is a layout what I want it to look like.

[image: ActionBar Drawable on top]

I want to put a drawable as shown in the picture atttached(The green color drawable not the notification thing). Is that possible to achieve this kind of screen in android? If, so please guide me how to achieve this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain ? which one you want to achieve ?

Comment: The big drawable "50" one. If that is achieved anything can be done with that. Right!

Comment: You can apply inner shadow for your text, that will help.

Comment: Please read the question I have asked. I have to place a drawable on top of the action bar. I don't have to use shadow and all.

Comment: Use a custom view for your action bar, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745447/action-bar-custom-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy using a custom view. Let me explain you the steps briefly:

1. Create your custom view in the layout folder. For example, an `ImageButton`.
2. Set this view as the custom view of the action bar in your activity. You can do this by calling

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_custom_view);
   ```

   (or `getActionBar()` instead of `getSupportActionBar()`)
3. Call `setDisplayOptions()` with the `ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME` and `ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM` options.
4. If you have other standard buttons in the action bar, inflate the menu.
5. You can finally set the `OnClickListener` for your custom view.

This worked for me, hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Can you please explain point number 3. How to achieve that? Do you have some working code for this?

Comment: Quite easy:           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

Comment: Hey Thank You for your answer, can you tell me how can I get onClickListener() on the custom view? I'm unable to get that.

Comment: customview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) { // Do stuff here }});

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom view
2. Use it as ActionView in ActionBar
3. In onCreateOptionsMenu get a reference to your view and update it when needed

Comment: @Anupam I have a link to official documentation, which you probably didn't read :) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: I read this documentation. But there was problem with that. I can only add items to actionbar with some specific size. But my requirement is different. I want to put a drawable which bigger than any of the action item images.

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_task"
          android:icon="@drawable/add"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>


inflate this xml in onCreateOptionMenu() but first put this xml into ur menu folder which is in res folder.

Comment: @Anupam you should use **Action View** not just **drawable**. It can be of any size.