# Set custom style and action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm developing an app that needs to work with action bar and tab bar, my first issue was to set up a custom text style for the label on the tab bar, now I want to use the action bar, but I'm having trouble with custom style and action bar. I made a custom style so:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745447/action-bar-custom-view) that I can add an action bar to a custom style, so i tried to do so:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

If you look at my xml code you can see that I add the Widget.ActionBar style to display an action bar on my activity. When I try to run my app I can see the custom style for the tab host, but I can't see the action bar.
I need action bar to put there a the share button.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/)?

Here it given to make actionbarserlock.

Comment: I inserted your solution, but it gives 12 errors... I post [here](http://postimg.org/image/4n67cramf/) the screenshot of my styles.xml, I hope you can help me to fix this issues, thank you

Comment: @lucgian84 Ohh Sorry. I have added ActionbarSerlock library in my project that's why you got error. Wait, let me update the answer.

Comment: I will take a look to your suggestion. Thank you for now

Comment: welcome... Please upvote it so it can help other also. Thanks again.

Comment: I voted for you, just a question, I'm trying to add this actionbar to my app, but how I can add it? I tried to follow the instruction provided on the site, but it's saying that it can't recognize this: `style="@style/ActionBar"`. What should I do to work with this action bar?